# How can I find documentation for the "s" object in Pure Data?

Tags: object, puredata

I'm looking at a Hanning window patch:

[image: Hanning window pure data patch]

In it, there is an object just called `s`. I'm guessing it writes its output to `$0-hann`. However, I'd like to know for certain, and I'm having trouble finding documentation for it either in the documentation that comes with Pure Data or online. The source for Pure Data is on GitHub, but `s` is very hard to search for. Does anyone know where I can find out definitively what it and other built-in objects do? To find out how `tabreceive` got its block size, I had to read the Pure Data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[s ]` is an alias for `[send]`. You can right-click the object and select `help` to display the help of the corresponding object.

Comment: Thank you! I found that out a few hours after I asked that, and it is invaluable.